# Elasticsearch 8.0.0 mapper_parsing_exception of a string literal for field type "flattened"

Tags: json, parsing, elasticsearch

I have a Problem to insert a document via Api to my ES 8.0.0.

In my IndexTemplate I defined a mapping of a property called [Data] of type "flattend".

For "normal" JSON-Objects it works fine. But when I try to insert a plain string literal (for example "test") or a number (for example 4) I get a "400 Bad Request". JSONLint says it's a valid JSON!!

```js
{
  ....
  "Data": "test",
  ....
}
```

Can i configure ES to accept such kind of JSON for type "flattened"??

Answer (score 0):

As Elasticsearch document mentions:

> The flattened type provides an alternative approach, where the entire
> object is mapped as a single field. Given an object, the flattened
> mapping will parse out its leaf values and index them into one field
> as keywords.

So, the value provided for the "flattened" field type should be a JsonObject.

Hence, below works as where "full_name" is of type "flattened"

```
"full_name":{
      "name":"nishikant"
    }
```

But below does not

```
"full_name":"nishikant".
```

Same has been given in exception

```
"reason" : "Failed to parse object: expecting token of type [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]"
```